# How to span User Interface across multiple Systems

Tags: .net, wpf, touch

I'm currently planning a large touch application build with WPF that runs on 5 borderless 46 inch screens. So the effective size of the application will be 9600x1080 pixels. Is there any way to allocate the application on multiple machines, so that I don't have to run the application on a single machine? It has to be that it is one giant application so parts of the ui can float between the screens.
Any help is highly appreciated!!!

Thanks!
Philipp

Comment: Why you need multiple machines? Just use single one with powerful graphic card

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think the answer's going to be it's not possible. I understand the motivation behind wanting multiple machines to run a large bank of monitors, but I don't think you can share an application between them. So you either need a powerful machine with multiple graphics cards, or run the application multiple times.

You might be to develop the application in a way that it can run in a mode to share session  information between computers and act together. You're not going to be able to drag windows around, but you might be able to implement a "Send to Screen X" command that tells the other instance to open the window.

It's not going to be an easy task though.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ray said, I don't think this will be possible in .Net as you've described it.

Though - I don't think it's much of a .Net question.

If you want to be able to span multiple monitors without huge workarounds - you only have one option: your computer must drive a display the size/shape you desire.

There are multiple ways to do this though. As others have suggested, I would also recommend just getting a good video card setup in the one computer and be done with it. If, for some reason, you have access to additional computers and cannot purchase hardware you could go with a software solution.

One example is a piece of software called MaxiVista (http://www.maxivista.com/) . It allows you to have computer A display part of its screen on the display of computer B. I believe it can also expand to more than just one additional computer. Keep in mind though - that this will require a good network connection between the computers.